# SQL WordPress get posts where serialized meta value is greater than todays date

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I've stored a bunch of post meta data inside a serialized array and I'm trying to write a custom SQL query that will only retrieve the results that are upcoming:

I'm currently at the following but It doesn't seem to want to get the results.

MY outputted SQL is:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'cjd' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cjd_data' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= 'date' ) ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC
```

And my functionality is:

```
$wpdb->query( 
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'cjd' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'cjd_data' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= 'date' ) ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC")
);
```

I've tried everything and I can't use meta_query on a custom $args as the date field is inside the serialized array.

Comment: Why are you saving all the values as an array? That's quite a handy technique when saving something like theme options but as you're finding out it's not as practical when handling data you need to act on in your queries.

Comment: Ha ha I know - At the start I was thinking it would be better for consistency - But now I'm strongly thinking of migrating each meta option out - any implications in terms of scale doing it that way??